# python module midi2audio does not convert input midi files to audio

Tags: python, audio, midi

I am trying to convert midi files to .wav files using midi2audio. The code is taken from the [documentation](https://pypi.org/project/midi2audio/) and doesn't throw any error. However, there doesn't seem to be any new wav file. Here are the code lines:

```
fs = FluidSynth()
fs.midi_to_audio('input.mid', 'output.wav')
```

I haven't found any useful information about my problem, neither in the documentation (I have fluidsynth installed, so that shouldn't be the problem) nor in other questions.

- notes: I'm using python 3.6

Any help will be appreciated

Comment: Maybe the file paths are incorrect? Is `input.mid` where it's supposed to be?

Comment: I have already checked it, they are correct

Comment: Maybe try using the absolute file path.

Comment: There is still no change...

Comment: it only displays information about fluidsynth

Comment: Did you try listening to the input file using `FuidSynth`?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/213144/discussion-between-c-sharp-and-mapf).

Answer (score 0):

do you have some fonts loaded ? run the program in debug mode to see the path required and put font files.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).